# How to add an ifblank to current formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula

```
=IF(D3-D4-D5-D8=D6,"Numbers ARE Correct","Numbers ARE NOT Correct")
```

How do I change it so that if the `D3,D4,D5,D8,D6` cells are all blank, it instead of showing either of the `TRUE/FALSE` bits from the original formula, it instead says

> Cells not populated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
=IF(COUNT(D3:D6,D8)=0,"",IF(D3-D4-D5-D8=D6,"Numbers ARE Correct","Numbers ARE NOT Correct"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTA` to count non blank cells:

```
=IF(COUNTA(D3,D4,D5,D6,D8)=0, “Cells Not Populated”,IF(D3-D4-D5-D8=D6,”Numbers ARE Correct”, “Numbers ARE NOT Correct”))
```

Comment: Or just a tad bit simplified, `=IF(COUNTA(D3:D6,D8)=0, “Cells Not Populated”,IF(D3-D4-D5-D8=D6,”Numbers ARE Correct”, “Numbers ARE NOT Correct”))`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I was half asleep when I typed that. :)